# How to send basic headers authentication in my .NET MAUI Windows desktop app?

Tags: c#, maui, dotnet-httpclient

I am creating a .NET MAUI desktop application, that uses an open API to show a map. The map shows up and works fine when the `MauiProgram.cs` file is configured with the following lines that triggers a window asking for a user name and password and in the username field the API key is entered and the password field is left empty:

```
.UseArcGISRuntime(config => config
  .ConfigureAuthentication(auth => auth
                .UseDefaultChallengeHandler()
            )
        )
```

Is it possible to omit the authentication window and have the API key set to the username in the background?

The map API documentation states that it is possible to send basic headers authentication. From My understanding, it should then be possible to omit the step where the app asks for authentication and "automatically" shows the map, or maybe I am wrong?!. And to do so I created the following `ViewMap.cs` class and tried to implement the headers authentication as follow:

```
public static class ViewMap
{

    public static async Task LoadWMTSLayer(MapView MyMapView)
    {
        try
        {
            //get value by key
            var apiKey = Keys.Instance["Settings:API-key"];

            // Create a new map.
            Map myMap = new();

            // Get the basemap from the map.
            Basemap myBasemap = myMap.Basemap;

            // Get the layer collection for the base layers.
            LayerCollection myLayerCollection = myBasemap.BaseLayers;

            // Create an instance for the WMTS layer.
            WmtsLayer myWmtsLayer;

            //specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection (Maybe not needed)
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            // Define the Uri to the WMTS service.
            Uri wmtsUri = new("https://avoin-karttakuva.maanmittauslaitos.fi/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/taustakartta/default/ETRS-TM35FIN/3/5/3.png?api-key=" + apiKey);

            // Create a new HttpClient.
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            // Set the base address of the HttpClient.
            var baseAddress = httpClient.BaseAddress = wmtsUri;

            // Attach the Authorization header with the API key as the username.
            string headAuth = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{apiKey}:"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headAuth);

            // Create a new HttpRequestMessage.
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, baseAddress);

            // Send the request and get the response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);


            // Check if the request was successful.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Get the response content.
                HttpContent content = response.Content;

                // Create a WMTS layer using a Uri and provide an Id value.
                myWmtsLayer = new WmtsLayer(baseAddress, "taustakartta");

                // Add the WMTS layer to the layer collection of the map.
                myLayerCollection.Add(myWmtsLayer);

                // Assign the map to the MapView.
                MyMapView.Map = myMap;
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the error response.
                string errorMessage = $"Request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}: {response.ReasonPhrase}";
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", errorMessage, "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `MauiProgram.cs` I add the following in place of the first example above:

```
.UseArcGISRuntime()
.UseArcGISToolkit();
```

**Edit:** Additionally, here is what the documentation says, incase I miss understood it:

*HTTP Basic Authentication*

*possible uses: use of the interface from geospatial information software, the self-programmed customer application or the browser (through the address box)*

*The URL of the interface query is transmitted to the service in the way the URL has been defined in the service documentation*

*For example, when using the interface service through the browser (through the browser address box) or with QGIS software, the customer software asks the user for a password and user ID – the user ID is then replaced with the API key, and the password can be left blank (See  Vihjeitä Maanmittauslaitoksen Maastotietokannan OGC API Features -palvelun käyttäjille.pdf on page 1.)*

***When using the interface service from a self-programmed customer application
an Authorisation header of the form Basic HTTP Authentication (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617) must be attached to each HTTPS request made to the interface service
the API key’s string must be set as the value of the user-id field in the Authorisation header, and the password field must be left empty***

*The advantage when using this alternative is that the URL links between the interface service resources work as such as long as each HTTPS request includes the Authorisation header described above."*

Source: https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/rajapinnat/api-avaimen-ohje